# Pull up imbalance

Tags: pull-ups, back, chin-ups, muscle-imbalance

I noticed that my pull ups are not symmetrical, I am going a bit to the right. I want to know where is the problem, is it stretch/mobility issue, or is it from muscle strenght, and if it is, what muscle specifically, is it traps, lats, rear delts, or all of them in some degree?[image: hold]
[image: contracted]
[image: chin up]

Comment: Do you have pain?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov not during pull ups. But after back workouts I sometimes feel some discomfort in right upper back, I wouldn't call that pain, rather some kind of tension or tightness, especially when i lean my head back or retract my right scapula.

Answer (score 1):

It could very likely be a spinal alignment issue.

I get occasional adjustments at the chiropractor. Often when I get an adjustment, they will find that one leg is longer than the other. After the adjustment, they are even.

I suspect something like this could be the issue. If you can get in to see a chiropractor, they can determine if your spine has kinks. Typically, these are simple to resolve.